# Theme using masonry layout script  rendering overlaped images in Google Chrome

Tags: images, jquery, css, browser-compatibility, google-chrome

I have a WordPress theme built with [Masonry script](http://masonry.desandro.com/) , I added a new template file for list gallery, is working ok in FF and IE but in Google Chrome gallery images (inside containers) are overlapped.

Seems like the content is loading faster than images but they don't adjust afterwards.

Comment: I did not migrate the question because it is too vague. The description does not allow anyone to recreate the problem, so it is hard to imagine how any future visitor could benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any reference about it but it seems Google Chrome (v 21.0.1180.60)  do need specified image sizes, in image tag or passing this in css (either class or local):

```
style="display:block;width:333px;height:333px"
```

Or:

```
container.img { display:block;width:333px;height:333px }
```

Maybe this issue has something to do with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971258/masonry-images-overlapping-issue), but I'm not sure.

They say images need width and height info in image tag, but some themes/plugins around aren't even informing `alt` tag.